# Pattern to avoid looping on virtual calls

Tags: c++, design-patterns

In my game I usually have every NPC / items etc being derived from a base class "entity". Then they all basically have a virtual method called "update" that I would class for each entity in my game at every frame. I am assuming that this is a pattern that has a lot of downsides. 
What are some other ways to manage different "game objects" throughout the game? Are there other well-known patterns for this?
I'm basically trying to find better model than to have everything derived from a base class, which would span a gigantic inheritance tree and virtual functions everywhere

Comment: What kind of downsides do you mean?

Comment: Its called an update *hint*. Included with the update is a *hint* about the scope in which it is called, and to perform appropriate (or even no) action. MS does this commonly in their MFC behemoth.

Comment: I'm not sure your current solution is all that bad. If you are going to be calling different code for the different objects, you can't get around some degree of indirection, and virtual methods are a pretty efficient way of doing that.

Comment: @amaurea : what I'm worried about is that it seems like the most naive approach, and usually you find out later that there are downsides

Comment: The plus operator is the most naive way to add two integers.  It's also the best.

Comment: Why does every object need to be updated every frame?  I can think of many kinds of object that do not need to know if time is passing, at least not on a per-frame basis.  About the only thing that your game engine should have change each frame is drawing, and `Update()` doesn't draw (does it?  Then why is it called `Update()`?).  Other behavior shouldn't be tied to frame rate.  If some object changes, its changes shouldn't be tied to frame rate: instead of `Update()` each frame, it should ask to be told when 1 second (or 0.1 seconds) have passed, and then not be run until that occurs, right?

Comment: @Yakk : you are exactly right, but to do what you are doing I am still calling Update() for every entity with the elapsed time since the last frame, and it updates itself or not (knowing that 1sec have passed for instance). That's why I'm looking for a better way to do it than looping every frame to test if I actually need an update or not

Comment: @Yakk You're right that game state updates shouldn't be tied to graphics updates; but, even in a 'real time' game, it still makes sense to think of game state updates in terms of discretized 'frames'; you just have a separate 'frame rate' for graphics and for game logic, and the 'game logic' framerate isn't supposed to be modifiable by the player (ie, it is psuedo-constant and defined by the game rules).

Answer (score 2):

There is another pattern that involves inheriting for behaviour instead.

For example: A sword (in a fantasy-styled game) could inherit from `Describable` to make it being able to be described to the player; It will also inherit from `DoDamage` which handles passing out damage; It further inherits from `Grabable` so the player can "grab" it.

A piece of armour in turn could inherit from `DamageReduction` to lower damage given, as well as `Wearable` so the player could wear it.

Instead of a big and deep inheritance tree, you get many smaller and shallower inheritance trees. The drawback is of course that you have to create lots of classes, and think about the different behaviour and events that can happen.

Comment: This can be a good way of doing things, but this answer could benefit from describing how such a model should connect to the game engine at large.  For example, if you try to iterate over all game objects, then somehow 'query interface' to see if the object is Grabable, and then conditionally process, things get ugly fast.  Another approach may be an update loop pattern that deals with 'pairs' of objects with compatible interfaces, e.g., CanWear and Wearable.  I am very curious what your preferred approach here is.

Comment: @WeirdlyCheezy To be honest I really haven't actually implemented a system such as this yet, only thought about experimenting with it for my next project. So I have no advice on how to solve this practically as of yet.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. I was curious because I'm implementing something similar to this right now as well.  In case it helps anyone, my current attempt is a 'game graph' where, for each possible 'edge type' (e.g. pair of node types), that edge is only allowed if at least one of the node types 'knows' how to process that pair.  ATM, the main update call collects nodes of a given type, looks at neighbors, and dispatches to pair-handlers (later I might use signalling if the graph gets too big),  Yet to see if this approach works well, so take it with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 1):

Have your objects request Updates at a certain point in time in the future.

```
struct UpdateToken {
  UpdateToken() {}
  /* ... */
};
class Updater {
  // ...
  struct UpdateEntry
  {
    UpdateToken token;
    Time when;
    bool repeats;
    Time frequency
    std::function<void()> callback;
  };
  // Various indexes into a collection of UpdateEntries
  // sorted by when and by token so you can look up both ways quickly
public:
  UpdateToken RegisterUpdate( Time t, std::function<void()> callback ); // once after time t
  UpdateToken RegularUpdate( Time t, std::function<void()> callback ); // every time t

  void UnregisterUpdate( UpdateToken );
};
Updater* GetUpdater();

// use:
class Foo
{
  UpdateToken token;

  void DoUpdate()
  {
    std::cout << "I did it!\n";
  }

  void PlanRepeatingUpdate( Time t )
  {
    if (!GetUpdater())
      return;
    if (token.valid())
      GetUpdater()->UnregisterUpdate(token);
    token = GetUpdater()->RegularUpdate( t, [&]()->void
    {
      this->DoUpdate();
    });
  }
  ~Foo() { if (token.valid() && GetUpdater()) GetUpdater()->UnregisterUpdate(token); }
};
```

Here we have a source of future events (the Updater()), and j random class Foo which can register a callback in it for one repeat, or a sequence of repeats.

You can ask for an update in 0.1 seconds, or in 1 second, or in 1 hour.  If you happen to be destroyed, or otherwise not want the update, you can Unregister it, and it never arrives.

Some effort has to be put into the Updater, so that it can both find the next events to call fast and can find updates by tokens.  I've seen a Boost doubly-indexed container, or you can handle it manually by having a primary std::set (or unordered set), and a secondary set of iterators to the first set with a unique ordering, that you manage quite carefully (you have to pay attention to what makes an iterator invalid, and make sure that the set of iterators contains nothing invalid).

The above also uses effectively a global Updater() instance, which isn't usually ideal.